# Is it necessary to reduce update times even use group by statement?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

There are two tables

Table A col1,col2,col3

- 100,200,aaa;
- 101,200,bbb;
- 102,200,ccc;

Table B col1,col2,col3

- aaa,1,ok;
- aaa,2,ok;
- aaa,3,ok;
- bbb,1,fine;
- bbb,3,fine;

Assume table A is a very large table and table B is a small table. In table B, col1 only have one col3 value, e.g, if col1 is 'aaa', col3 must be 'ok'

case 1:

```
update a set a.col2 = b.col3
from A a, B b
where a.col3 = b.col1
```

case 2:

```
update a set a.col2 = b.col3
from A a, (select col1, col3 from B group by col1,col3) b
where a.col3 = b.col1
```

The result of case 1 and case 2 are the same, but I just want to ask which statement is better? Whether case 1 will update table A for 5 times? Will the group by statement in case 2 consume more calcuation?

Comment: Note in tableB, col3 is transitively dependent on col3, which is not a candidate key. You *could* use : `update A SET a.col2 = x.col3 FROM (SELECT col3, MIN(col3) AS col3 FROM B GROUP BY col1) X ON A.col3 = X.col1;`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sql server, table B is a temp table without index so will the exection plan be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run `EXPLAIN` on both these queries to see how your database is actually handling things.  That being said, one thing does stand out in terms of performance.  In your first query:

```
update a set a.col2 = b.col3
from A a, B b
where a.col3 = b.col1
```

you are joining table `A` with `B` via the `col3` and `col1` columns.  If there were an index on `B.col1` then the join could proceed much faster than if the database were forced to do a full table scan of `B`.  But an index on `B.col1` probably would not help in your second query:

```
update a set a.col2 = b.col3
from A a, (select col1, col3 from B group by col1,col3) b
where a.col3 = b.col1
```

Here you are joining `A` to a table derived from `B` and as such no index is likely available.  So I would opt for your first query.

By the way, you are using the old pre ANSI-92 syntax for joining in your first query and you might want to update it.

Comment: His second query is effectively removing all duplicate `col1`, `col3` pairs, which could also be achieved by using `DISTINCT`.  But in either case, I think an index would not be possible on `B`.

Comment: Tim, (1) since "table A is a very large table and table B is a small table" playing around with B won't change much. (2) I'm guessing you are coming from MySQL. Databases that supports HASH JOIN do need any indexes in order to support O(n) join. (3) There is no filtering,so in any case this is going to be full table scan for both tables. In databases that do not support HASH JOIN index on A.col2 will support MERGE JOIN in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Since these 2 statements are logically equal (result wise) they might have the same execution plan and therefore have the same performance.
Different execution plans might give an advantage to each of the statements.

I would like to emphasize one thing -
Nested-loops is not the only option to implement JOIN and in databases that support HASH JOIN they are rarely used for equality JOIN therefore the all way you are thinking about what is going here needs to be revised.

Comment: Could you please explain more that dedup in the 2nd query is pointless as I can physically see 5 lines of data there -- would sql server automatically optmize the data to 2 rows(aaa, ok/bbb, fine) when process the update query or it would just update 5 times?

Comment: @YvetteColomb, The point was not to display a wrong answer while I'm writing a new one. however I checked now and I realize an answer can be edited while deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128434/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-yvette-colomb).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, according to sql execution plan, it will dedup data going to update at background so no need to distinct manually, see below screenshot.

[sql server automatically sort/distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gUyY.png)